# Can we create react native app without "create-react-native-app" cli?

Tags: react-native

Do we always need this "create-react-native-app" utility or we can set up manually? I wanted to know if there is any other way to setup for working with react-native.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
$ npm install -g react-native-cli
$ react-native init AwesomeProject
$ cd AwesomeProject
$ react-native run-ios/android
```

#### Explanation:

`$ npm install -g react-native-cli` installs a global npm package from Facebook to create a native project.

`$ react-native init AwesomeProject` will create a blank app with the data structure.

`$react-native run-ios/android` will compile your application and install on your device.

Comment: sure npm install -g react-native-cli will install a global module for react 
next command will create initial app with a demo screen 
last command will run native app

Comment: @Jigar gave you the correct answer but there are a few additional steps. You can check out [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) to see this. Click the **Build Projects With Native Code** tab on the linked documentation page.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I appreciate your help.